# How to debug `AnimationVideo` "does not yield valid frames" error?

Tags: plotting

I have the following code below producing working `Animation` but failing `AnimationVideo` in Mathematica 14.0.0.0. Error is "does not yield valid frames" and error tooltip is "Improperly formatted option" (what option?). How do I debug this?

```
dist[n_] = 
  TransformedDistribution[(1 - 2  x/n), 
   x \[Distributed] ChiSquareDistribution[n]];
pdf[n_, x_] = PDF[dist[n], x];

comboPlot[b_] := Module[{labeledPdf, boundaryPlot, mainPlot, x, SF},
   SF = StringForm;
   nf[expr_] := NumberForm[N@expr, {3, 3}];
   labeledPdf = Labeled[pdf[b, x], SF["b=``", nf@b], {Top}];
   boundaryPlot = 
    ListPlot[{{1, 1.1}, {-1, 1.1}}, Filling -> Axis, 
     PlotLegends -> {"stability"}];
   mainPlot = 
    Plot @@ {labeledPdf, {x, -2, 2}, 
      PlotLegends -> {SF["b=``", nf@b]}, PlotLabel -> "1-x", 
      AxesLabel -> {"x", "density"}, Ticks -> {True, False}}
   ];
Animate[comboPlot[b], {b, 1, 2}]
AnimationVideo[comboPlot[b], {b, 1, 2}]
```

Comment: The documentation for `AnimationVideo` mentions that its first argument must evaluate to either `Image` or `Graphics`. Your `comboPlot` evaluates to an expression with head `Legended`, so it is rejected.

Comment: Ah thanks, looks like it's not compatible with the `PlotLegends->` option